# I have Year & Month but need to incorpate month number also

Tags: oracle11g

This is my value in the table : FY20 JAN

And i am looking for 'FY20 (M01) JAN'. How can convert like this in Oracle 11g SQL query ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, your question is understandable, but sometimes it helps to say what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

First you convert your string to a value of DATE type. Anything enclosed in double quotes is somewhat hard coded and TO_DATE function ignores them as long as they match the characters in the input in their specific locations. Here FY are in location (index) 1 and 2.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';              
select to_date('FY20 JAN', '"FY"yy MON') d from dual;

D         
----------
2020-01-01
```

Then, you apply another function TO_CHAR to the date value we got above to get the desired output.

```
select to_char(
                to_date('FY20 JAN', '"FY"YY MON')
                , '"FY"yy "(M"mm")" MON'
              ) c from dual;

C                      
-----------------------
FY20 (M01) JAN
```